# RSYNC with many files using `files-from`

Tags: bash, centos, command, rsync

I have multiple files named like `exported-0.txt` and `exported-1.txt` and `exported-2.txt` (sequential suffixes)... and inside each file there is an absolute file path per line. For example, the file `exported-1.txt` has a content like this:

```
/directory1/img.png
/aabb/file.csv
/magic/file/boo/aaa/cc.jpg
...
```

I understand that `rsync` allows the usage of `--files-from` from where `rsync` will read all the files inside that file and use that to syncronize to another server. The problem is that I have thousands of `exported-N.txt` files and each file has thousands of lines.

So I am wondering the best approach to execute in parallel, for example 5 `rsync`, each call on a different file that contains thousands of lines of files that need to be syncronized.

I have almost no knowledge on command line in Linux so I have no idea where to start. I am wondering if I can use `xargs` to generate numbers from 1-9999 in order for it to call `rsync` on each file + number. But I cant find a way to do that... Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a bash solution for processing your `exported-*.txt` files with `n` concurrent `rsync`s.

The main idea is to concatenate a "computed" number of `exported-*.txt` files inside a process substitution `<(...)` and using the latter as file argument of `--files-from`:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s nullglob

n=5

arr=( exported-*.txt )

(( len = ${#arr[@]} / n + 1 ))
(( rem = ${#arr[@]} % n ))

idx=0
while (( idx < ${#arr[@]} ))
do
    (( rem-- == 0 )) && (( len-- ))
    rsync -a --files-from=<(cat -- "${arr[@]:idx:len}") /your/remote/dir/ &
    (( idx += len ))
done

wait
```

Comment: That's a really nice code however there is a problem. The `rsync` command gets executed but it goes to background (because of the `&` symbol at the end of your line) and unfortunately I cant type the password of my server. I am using a remote server to send the files to, so when I execute `rsync` it should ask me the password of the remote server however the process went to background so I cant type the password.

Comment: @Jonathan I don't think that you can run multiple `rsync` in parallel if they ask for a password. The usual way is to configure SSH keys for getting rid of the password prompt

Comment: Indeed, you are correct. However I see many people using `xargs` to execute `rsync` in parallel.. do you think that using `xargs` your code could benefit from it?

Comment: @Jonathan No, `xargs` won't be able to fix the password prompt problem. Also, the method here forks 5 `rsync`s in total while `xargs` would fork one `rsync` per `exported-*.txt` file

Comment: Thank you! I remade this question in another link I think you might help since it looks like you know this very well -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74582740/using-multiple-rsync-without-waiting-completion