# Using multiple `rsync` without waiting completion

Tags: linux, bash, centos, rsync, scp

I have this code below which loops `rsync` several times in different directories:

```
for (( i=0; i<6; i++ )); do

    rsync /source-${i} /remote-destination
    
done
```

However there is a problem: when it executes the first `rsync`, it asks me the password of the remove server and then it starts transfering the files. Only after it finishes transfering all the files it executes the loop a second time, asks me the password of the remote server again (no problem, I can afford typing the password every single time) and then I need to wait the transfer to happen so it can continue.

I would like the loop to continue, without waiting... I tried using the `&` char at the end of the command line to send it to background however if I do that, I cant type the password of the remote server!

Any idea how I can solve this? I really want to type myself the password every single time, this is not a problem. The problem is that or the loop waits every single `rsync` to be completed or it sends the password prompt to the background if I use `&`.

Answer (score 0):

Look into the `rsync` [online man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync), and it has an opinion called `--password-file`.

Here are some original texts:

> You can avoid the password prompt by setting the environment variable RSYNC_PASSWORD to the password you want to use or using the --password-file option. This may be useful when scripting rsync.

Comment: This solution of yours only work when `rsync` is running as a daemon, which most of the time is not how it's running. Unfortunatelly I am running the code on a server where I cant set rsync to run as a daemon :(

Answer (score 0):

This is really an `ssh` question.  You have to create ssh keys and copy them to the remote host - see [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/configuring-ssh-login-without-password) for some good directions.

Until you can do:

```
$ ssh remotehost hostname
remotehost
```

without entering a password rsync will require a password.

Comment: But I really would like to type the password... Isnt there an alternative in such a way that right after I type the password, then I press something like CTRL+Z in such a way that it places the rsync in background and keeps the loop running to the next iteration?